# .wrapAll() based on adjacent siblings' class and

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I have a series of DIVs that are assigned `.big` or `.small` based on size. They need to be wrapped in groups of two or three. Practically speaking, only two `.big`s can fit in the allotted space.

If two `.big` DIVs exist adjacent to one another, they should be wrapped in groups of two. Otherwise, the DIVs should be wrapped in groups of three.

Please let me know what I've done wrong and how to make it work. Below is an example with comments on where the wraps should break. Below that is what I've tried in jQuery, and a [link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/natejones/UvsZE/).

```
<div class="big post">big</div>
<div class="big post">big</div>
    <!-- should be wrap break -->
<div class="big post">big</div>
<div class="big post">big</div>
    <!-- should be wrap break -->
<div class="big post">big</div>
<div class="small post">small</div>
<div class="big post">big</div>
    <!-- should be wrap break -->
<div class="small post">small</div>
<div class="small post">small</div>
<div class="big post">big</div>
    <!-- should be wrap break -->
<div class="big post">big</div>
<div class="small post">small</div>
    <!-- should be wrap break -->
```

I think the `if`, below, works pretty well, but the `else` breaks all the things.

```
$('.post').each(function() {    
    if ( $(this).hasClass('big') && $(this).next('.post').hasClass('big') ) {    
        var allElements = $(this).next().andSelf(),
            WRAP_BY = 2;
        for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i += WRAP_BY) {
            allElements.slice(i, i + WRAP_BY).andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="flowed" />');
        }//for                            
    }//if
else {
    // the else breaks all the things
        var allElements = $(this).next().andSelf(),
            WRAP_BY = 3;
        for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i += WRAP_BY) {
            allElements.slice(i, i + WRAP_BY).andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="flowed" />');
        }//for                                        
}//else
});//each
```

http://jsfiddle.net/natejones/UvsZE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first - you need to return from function, if elements, already wrapped,

second, i not understand why you need `for` loop in `else`(you can use `$.nextAll()` to get all sibling after current)

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/UvsZE/14/) the code

```
$('.post').each(function() {
    //return if already wrapped!
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('flowed')) {
        return;
    }
    var WRAP_BY = 3;
    if ($(this).hasClass('big') && $(this).next('.post').hasClass('big')) {
        WRAP_BY = 2;
    }
    var allElements = $(this).nextAll().andSelf();
    allElements.slice(0, WRAP_BY).wrapAll('<div class="flowed" />');
}); //each​
```

Comment: I also prefer to make $(this) a variable and you it in function like `var $this=$(this)`;